# Returning a float variable loses its precision in C

Tags: c, function, floating-point, return

Hi yes I am having some trouble with the following code. The function above executes and outputs 132.87 to the float variable but when I return this back to the main program the output is then shortened to 132.00

This is obviously something simple I am missing can anyone help me with this one please?
Much appreciated.

```
calcSigmaXY(max) {
 int count= 0;
 float runTotal = 0, product[max];
 for (count = 1; count <= max; count++) {
     product[count] = pointData[count][1] * pointData[count][2];
     runTotal = runTotal + product[count];
 }
 printf("\nruntotal is %4.2f",runTotal); // outputs 132.87
 return(runTotal);
} 

int maxPoints = 6;
float sigmaXY = 0,
sigmaXY = calcSigmaXY(maxPoints);
printf("\nsigmaxy set to : %4.2f\n", sigmaXY); // outputs 132.00
```

Comment: I don't see the signature of `calcSigmaXY(max)`, is this valid standard C code? Probably return type of the fuction is `int` so your return value gets converted.

Comment: Thank you Jack, bit of a noob mistake on my part.

Comment: @MatthewWalton I would recommend turning on warnings in your compiler, and making warnings be errors so you can't ignore them. If you're using GCC or Clang, you should be able to pass the flags `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to turn on the most useful warnings and cause the compile to fail when you get a warning. I don't know what the MSVC equivalent is, but I'm sure there is one. That will help you avoid a lot of possible noob mistakes.

Answer (score 10):

In some C versions, return values & types default to `int`, so by declaring your function like

```
calcSigmaXY(max)
```

you're basically saying

```
int calcSigmaXY(max)
```

ergo the loss of precision - the `float` you return is converted to an `int`. Declare your function as

```
float calcSigmaXY(max) {
      //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the return value of `calcSigmaXY`, otherwise the return value is `int` implicitly.

If you declare your function as `float calcSigmaXY` it should work as intended.

Also consider enabling and reading warnings in your compiler/IDE.